# how to print file path location in imce drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, imce-file-browser

i want display the file location path in the imce : 
i opened the imce-file-list.tpl.php and i found that :

```
 <tr id="<?php print $raw = rawurlencode($file['name']); ?>">
        <td class="name"><?php print $raw; ?></td>
        <td class="size" id="<?php print $file['size']; ?>"><?php print format_size($file['size']); ?></td>
        <td class="width"><?php print $file['width']; ?></td>
        <td class="height"><?php print $file['height']; ?></td>
        <td class="date" id="<?php print $file['date']; ?>"><?php print format_date($file['date'], 'short'); ?></td>
      </tr>
```

i want print $file[path] but it not working
[image]

Comment: Do you try $file['path']  with quotes?

Comment: yes but not worked, i want show the directory name, i tryed also : dirname, but also not working

Comment: Hey man, try  $imce['furl']  and $imce['dir'] Font: [https://www.drupal.org/node/1738218#comment-10674360]

Comment: Thnx man :D :D worked with $imce['furl']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salaktarus,

Try use **$imce['furl']** variable.

From [drupal.org/node/1738218#comment-10674360](http://drupal.org/node/1738218#comment-10674360)